# Get return from javascript function to html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in ones of my views

```
  <%= link_to rating_book_path(@book, :rate => HERE_I_WANT_THE_SCORE_RETURNED_BY_FUNCTION), style: "text-decoration: none;" do %>
     <div id="rating" data-score="1" onclick="getScore();"></div>
  <% end %>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#rating').raty('reload'); //Previene el error de que al volver atras o ir adelante se muestren más estrellas de las debidas
        $('#rating').raty({
            path: '/assets/'
        });
    })
    function getScore(){
      return $('#rating').raty('score');
    }
  </script>
```

What I need is the value returned by the function `getScore()` gets placed next to `:rate =>` symbol, so the link to it redirect is something like: `/books/5/rating_book?rate=THE_VALUE_RETURNED_BY_THE_FUNCTION` (i.e: `/books/5/rating_book?rate=3`)

Maybe can help that the ruby helper is translated to html like this:

```
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/books/5/rating_book?rate=5">
     <div id="rating" data-score="1" onclick="getScore();" style="cursor: pointer;">
     <img alt="1" src="/assets/star-on.png" title="bad">&nbsp;
     <img alt="2" src="/assets/star-off.png" title="poor">&nbsp;
     <img alt="3" src="/assets/star-off.png" title="regular">&nbsp;
     <img alt="4" src="/assets/star-off.png" title="good">&nbsp;
     <img alt="5" src="/assets/star-off.png" title="gorgeous">
     <input name="score" type="hidden" value="1"></div>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem doing this:

```
    function getScore(){
      var hrefAttr = document.getElementById("rating-link").getAttribute("href"); // /books/5/rating_book?rate=5
      var hrefTrunk = hrefAttr.slice(0, hrefAttr.length-1); // /books/5/rating_book?rate=
      console.log(hrefTrunk + $('#rating').raty('score')); // DEBUG: concat with new score
      document.getElementById("rating-link").setAttribute("href", hrefTrunk + $('#rating').raty('score'));
    }
```

And I added `id: "rating-link"` like an attribute for link_to

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to rating_book_path(@book, :rate => HERE_I_WANT_THE_SCORE_RETURNED_BY_FUNCTION), style: "text-decoration: none;" do %>
  <div id="rating" data-score="1"></div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rating').raty('reload'); //Previene el error de que al volver atras o ir adelante se muestren más estrellas de las debidas
    $('#rating').raty({
      path: '/assets/'
    });

    $("#rating img").mouseover(function(){
      $('#rating').data('score', this.alt)
    });

    $('#rating').click(function(){
      return $('#rating').raty('score');
    });
  });
  </script>
```